# do_patch: Function failed: patch_do_patch -- running bitbake

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am using yocto build a linux image that integrates some layers of wlan and a specific wifi chip, but seems like patching of one of the files is failing (details below)

Steps that I did:

- Created a working directory
- initialized a repo for kernel 4.14.98 via:

```
repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-manifest -b imx-linux-sumo -m imx-4.14.98-2.3.3.xml
```

- sync the repo via `repo sync`
- created a `tmp` folder outside of the current working dir, and download the specific code for wifi via

```
repo init -u git://codeaurora.org/quic/le/le/manifest.git -b release -m CHSS.LNX_FSLS.1.0-01200-QCAAUTOHOSTHZ.xml –repo-url=git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git –repo-branch=caf-stable
```

- repo the sync
- copy the `meta-qti-connectivity` and `wlan-opensource` folders into the source folder of the working directory
- Download the files for a specific wifi chip and copy over `meta-qticonnectivity-prop` and `wlanproprietary` into the source folder of the working directory

So now we have added additional 4 directories into the source folder of the working directory

- Set up the build environment
- Run `bitbake core-image-minimal`

and I see the following error:

```
ERROR: wpa-supplicant-git-r0 do_patch: Command Error: 'quilt --quiltrc <working_directory>/linux_image/build/tmp/work/imx8qxpmek-poky-linux/wpa-supplicant/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc push' exited with 0  Output:
Applying patch 0009-Sync-with-mac80211-next.git-include-uapi-linux-nl802.patch
patching file src/drivers/nl80211_copy.h
...
15 out of 20 hunks FAILED -- rejects in file src/drivers/nl80211_copy.h
Patch 0009-Sync-with-mac80211-next.git-include-uapi-linux-nl802.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
ERROR: wpa-supplicant-git-r0 do_patch: Function failed: patch_do_patch
```

- I'm new to yocto, and from the looks of it, it seems the patch `0009-Sync-with-mac80211-next.git-include-uapi-linux-nl802.patch` didn't apply, but does that mean the issue is with the patch file or the way it's referenced.

This patch file resides in the `meta-fsl-bsp-release` layer under `wpa-supplicant` sub directory, which I DID NOT add manually. This sub-directory has a `.bbappend` file that refers to these patch files via `SRC_URI` variable, but it doesn't contain any `.bb` file.

One of the meta layers that I added has `wpa-supplicant` sub-directory as well but it only has `.bb` file and no `.bbappend`.

I'm confused as to how are these two subdirectories different or could they conflict in anyway? Also, shouldn't the subdirectory have both the `.bbappend` & a corresponding `.bb` file?

- The `SRC_URI` variable is used to locate the applicable patch files and `do_patch` isn't needed in the respective `.bb` file of wpa-supplicant, right?
- the respective bb file `wpa-supplicant` has the following:

```
SRC_URI = "file://wlan-opensource/wpa_supplicant_8/"
SRC_URI += "file://hostapdconf \
            file://supplicantconf \
```

shouldn't patch files be defined with `.patch` at the end?

Also, I see in the yocto documentation that the path defined in `file://` is relative to the `FILESPATH` variable, which in the `bb` file is defined to be `"${BSPDIR}/sources:"` - not certain of `BSPDIR` itself but I think it's referring to `<top_dir>/sources`, but does that mean `hostapdconf` is supposed to be at `<top_dir>/sources`? I don't see it there but in other sub directory

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you have added a .bbappend for the wpa-supplicant recipe in a version that does not match the recipe. Likely the .bbappend is from one of the meta layers you copied into your source tree manually (`meta-qti-connectivity` or `wlan-opensource`).

> I'm new to yocto, and from the looks of it, it seems the patch
> 0009-Sync-with-mac80211-next.git-include-uapi-linux-nl802.patch didn't
> apply, but does that mean the issue is with the patch file or the way
> it's referenced?

Likely the patch is targetet at a different version of the source file.

> The SRC_URI variable is used to locate the applicable patch files and
> do_patch isn't needed in the respective .bb file of wpa-supplicant,
> right?

Right, if you don't see it explicitly ly in the .bb. The default do_patch task will be used.

> the respective bb file wpa-supplicant has the following:
>
> SRC_URI = "file://wlan-opensource/wpa_supplicant_8/" SRC_URI +=
> "file://hostapdconf 
> file://supplicantconf \ shouldn't patch files be defined
> with .patch at the end?

The .patch file is probably referenced by name in a .bbappend if you dont see it in the .bb file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I'm trying to understand. The `.bbappend` files have the same root names as their corresponding recipe `.bb` files. So in your first comment, are you implying the version number of the `.bbappend` doesn't align with that of the corresponding recipes of `meta-qti-connectivity` and `wlan-opensource`?

Comment: also, from my understanding after reading up, `bblayers.conf` file should contain the layers that we need to include via `BBLAYERS` variable. I already see the `meta-qti-connectivity-prop`, `meta-qti-connectivity` layers included so that seems okay

Comment: also based on my first comment, does that mean the `bbappend` file does exist for particularly the recipe for wpa supplicant? my understanding is bbappend file includes multiple recipes and not necessarily just one, but I don't see any `bbappend` file with the same root name as that of the recipe file, which corresponds to your potential reasoning behind the error (version number being different)

Comment: Th bbappend applies to one recipe only. It will apply to the recipe with the coresponding base name. A bbappend can be specified with (or without version or with wildcards in the version). A bbappend without version will apply to ALL versions of the corresponding recipes while a versioned bbappend will only apply to the recipe with the correct version. Therefore, a unversioned bbappend can be applied to a recipe that it was not intended for if you are not careful.

Comment: thing is I see one `wpa-supplicant` subdirectory in one of the meta layers I added, and the other in an already existing layer one namely `meta-fsl-bsp-release`. In the latter layer structure, I only see `.patch` files along with the `wpa-supplicant_%.bbappend` file which I believe applies to ALL versions of the corresponding recipes but I don't see any specific recipe `.bb` file under the same sub-directory - Does that mean I need create the `.bb` files myself?

Comment: Also the `wpa-supplicant_%.bbappend` file does reference all the patches in the existing directory via `SRC_URI`. 
And in the former subdirectory, I see a `.bb` file without no version and just a couple source files, and no `.bbappend`.  Does that mean I need to create a `.bbappend` file? But regarding versioning, I don't see any specific version being specified for corresponding `.bbappend` file